# redshift:GetClusterCredentials + dbuser + ${aws:username}

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have met a problem.
The idea was to pass the federated `(IDP)` `AWS` user name to `Redshift` as login using temporary credentials in the `AWS Redshift` query console.
But the user should able to connect only to his Redshift user id.
To use it, we did such a code.
`Redshift` has already all created before users.

```
 {
  "Sid": "Sid",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": "redshift:GetClusterCredentials",
   "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:redshift:eu-west-1:account_number:dbuser:cluster_name/${aws:username}",
                "arn:aws:redshift:eu-west-1:account_number:dbname:cluster_name/db_name"
            ]
 }
```

But `Redshift` uses only low letters in user id `(useid = "user_test")`, and `${aws:username}` returns only big letters `("USER_TEST")`.
In our case, we can not change the value in `${aws:username}`, because it is coming in the end from the `IDP` service.
Is it possible to make an expression somehow to make it equals?

Thank you!
Ivan

Answer (score 2):

StringEqualsIgnoreCase in IAM condition can help:

```
{
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "redshift:GetClusterCredentials",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:redshift:eu-west-1:account_id:dbname:cluster_name/db_name",
                "arn:aws:redshift:eu-west-1:account_id:dbuser:cluster_name/${redshift:DbUser}"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEqualsIgnoreCase": {
                    "aws:userid": "role_id:${redshift:DbUser}"
                }
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for a db username that matches the aws users's `aws:username`:

```
        {
          Sid      = "VisualEditor2"
          Effect   = "Allow"
          Action   = "redshift:GetClusterCredentials"
          Resource = [
            "arn:aws:redshift:*:123456789101:dbname:clusterid/dbid",
            "arn:aws:redshift:*:123456789101:dbuser:clusterid/${redshift:dbUser}"
          ]
          Condition = {
            StringEqualsIgnoreCase = {
              "aws:username" = "${redshift:dbUser}"
            }
          }
        }
```